# Get all of string after a character, if there's a space break

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Attempting to get all alphanumeric chars after `:` symbol unless a space exists, in which case the space will be the terminating mark.

```
// the following should all return foo
text = 'a :foo bar';   
text = 's:foo';
text = ':foo, test';
```

Tried this, but doesn't get stuff unless there's a space. I'll probably need a regex, but not sure how that would be constructed

```
var t = following.substring(following.lastIndexOf(":")+1,following.lastIndexOf(' '));
```

Comment: there is no space after foo here: `text = ':foo, test';`

Comment: Is it something like this you're after? http://www.regexr.com/38vfm

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte ',' is not alphanumeric

Comment: @kylex: if I understand well the space break is not needed?

Comment: A space break is not alphanumeric, so why the `unless`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about: `/:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/`

```
':foo, test'.match(/:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/)[1] //returns foo
's:foo'.match(/:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/)[1] //returns foo
':foo, test'.match(/:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/)[1] //returns foo
```

These RegEx uses 2 parts:

- **`:`** finds the `:` followed by
- **`[a-zA-Z0-9]+`** any alphanumeric character

> **Note**: 
>   Since this Regulars Expressions matches the types of characters I specified there is not need in this case to "break on space" since it will only match the alphanumeric characters after `:` it will automatically exclude space, comma, etc. any other character included within the square brackets will make that character a possible match.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using regular expressions, such as (albeit untested):

```
var result = text.match(/:([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s/)[1];
```

References:

- [javascript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: I don't see a reason to downvote this answer. (however, don't forget the 0)

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex like this

```
/:([\w]+)[\W]/g
```

Comment: Explaining the innards of the regex would be useful :-)